# Removing contractions

Tags: java, string, text-processing

I would like to remove all apostrophes from an input String of English prose, but retain the original meaning and capitalisation, ie

- isn't --> is not
- I'm --> I am
- they're --> they are
- shouldn't --> should not
- can't --> can not
- John's --> Johns (good enough)

What's the best/simplest way to achieve this in java?

Comment: Why would `John's` map to `Johns`?

Comment: @irrelephant what else would it map to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some hard and fast rules for replacing contractions.  Just have a method that performs those functions on your strings.

```
public String removeContractions(String inputString) { 

    inputString = inputString.replaceAll("n't", " not");
    inputString = inputString.replaceAll("'re", " are");
    inputString = inputString.replaceAll("'m", " am");
    inputString = inputString.replaceAll("'ll", " will");
    inputString = inputString.replaceAll("'ve", " have");

    return inputString;
}
```

This will even preserve your possessives.

Of course, there are some contractions which are dependent upon context, such as `he'd`.  This could be "he could", "he would", "he had", etc., and as such is beyond simple replacement algorithms and more in the realm of machine learning.

```
public String removeControversialContractions(String inputString) {

    inputString = inputString.replaceAll("'d", " would");
    inputString = inputString.replaceAll("'s", "s");

    return inputString;
}
```

Perhaps for the `'s` you could check to see if the word containing it begins with a capital letter (indicating a name) and conditionally replace it with either `s` or `is`.  However, this wouldn't catch normal contractions at the beginning of sentences, so...

If you want a simple *and* perfect approach, I'm not sure you'll get one.  To do these more complicated things, you'll need either a large dictionary file which you constantly reference or machine learning techniques.

Comment: `inputString = inputString.replaceAll("'s", "s");` see last example.

Comment: Yeah, you could add that, but I took the spirit of the question to be to preserve possessives if at all possible. :)  Perhaps that's not the intent, though, in which case that might be a good addition.

Comment: @Bohemian There is a space already. :)  At least, I see one on my screen.  `("n't", " not");`

Comment: This seems to be the best answer. Handling `'s` is tricky as you pointed out. Eg "It's good" = "It **is** good", but "It's been good" = "It **has** been good". Possibly "'s been" --> " has been", then "'s" --> " is".

Answer (score 9):

Have a contraction dictionary `Map<String, String>` that maps contractions to their spelled out form. Because there's no single rule for what an apostrophe replaces, this dictionary approach the way to go.

Comment: What about all the possessives? What about retaining capitalisation?

Comment: `Bob's a pony` vs `Bob's pony is named Bob`

Comment: Right. So that's an inherent ambiguity which is precisely why I advocate for the dictionary approach. There's no "hard and fast rule" for 's, but certainly there are some that can be contained in the dictionary. i.e. *Bob's* would not be replaced, but *it's* always would map to *it is*(since the possive form is *its*). Sure, if there are some unambiguous rules you can code those first but it should be together with a dictionary since that allows more precision in distinguishing between ambiguous and unambiguous cases

Comment: @irr "Bobs a pony" is fine